# animation on surface view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a framelayout as root layout. Under that, I have my custom surface view layout,textview and button view like this(this is just a sample testing code, not my real application code).

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <android.dipsy.org.canvastest.SurfaceViewExample
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLICK"
            android:onClick="btnClick"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

What I want is to set a background image and on top of that, I want to do some animation(moving bitmaps etc) on surface view. But the problem is when I set some background to framelayout or surface view, the animation is not visible.so how to solve this problem? or is my approach wrong?Is it possible to set a background for surfaceview and do animation on top of it?

Comment: What makes you think it is an issue with the layout? Are you drawing the background first and then the animation? And since surface view is by default behind all your views have you experimented with setZOrderOnTop(true)?

Comment: I have tried setting the background color in given activity layout.Both in framelayout and in surfaceview. I have not tried setZOrderOnTop. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: On a surfaceview you normally have a dedicated renderthread and you have to do all the drawing yourself. So...get a bitmap...set the bounds, draw it at x,y as you like.

Comment: I tried setZOrderOnTop(true) inside surfaceCreated method.But its not working.whenever I set a background color for either framelayout or surfaceview it hides the animation.

Comment: the problem is when i set a background in surface view animation is  not visible. that's what I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.Its simple but took some time to hit me. the trick is don't set your background in layout file,draw it! All I did was draw the background bitmap just before drawing the moving bitmap each time as below.

```
 pm.getPosTan(distance,pos,null); // pm is the pathMeasure object.
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(paper,0,0,p); //paper is the bitmap I wanted to set as background
            canvas.drawBitmap(ic,pos[0],pos[1],p); // ic is the moving bitmap
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```